# Snowflake-sdk NodeJS Resulting in error "Failed to fetch"

Tags: node.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a react app which makes a request to a nodejs server which connects to a snowflake warehouse using snowflake-sdk package.

All of this is deployed on HEROKU
Even locally it only works on certain pcs

It works fine and dandy ... but only on certain PCs?
My hypothesis is that a pc connecting from the same network is refused a connection because maybe it's already connected?

So I tried connecting before executing a query and then terminating it afterward which let to a new problem being that once terminated it doesn't allow me to reconnect.

I tried using a connection pool to no avail.

I searched around and keep seeing people talking about "keep connection alive" but that seems to only matter for long periods of inactivity, from what I've read the connection is by default kept alive for 4 hours or something like that.

Comment: Do you have any logs from the NodeJS driver?

Answer (score 0):

I am an idiot.
The client was making a call to localhost:3001
The reason it worked on certain pcs at certain times was when they were running the node server